# npm install from git use https instead ssh

Tags: git, npm

I have an application with the following package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "package_name": "git+ssh://git@git.scm.domain.com:Domain/package_name.git",
}
```

I can't change it and I can't use ssh. I tried

```
git config --global url.https://.insteadOf git://
git config --global url.https://git.scm.domain.com.insteadOf git://git.scm.domain.com
```

But `npm i` still throws an error about permission and I see that the url doesn't contain https protocol.

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! path to git.exe ls-remote -h -t git@git.scm.domain.com:Domain/repo.git
```

Is it possible to setup git or npm to use https instead of ssh while installing deps from package.json?

Comment: `git+ssh://git@git.scm.domain.com` is an SSH URL while your replacements use `git://` protocol.

Comment: @phd I've just updated question. please check npm error. there is no `git+ssh`

Comment: Your example of the JSON file contains `git+ssh://`, which is an older synonym for `ssh://`.  Also, does that URL contain a colon or a slash? It would never have worked at all with a colon.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

This works perfectly. Also pay attention to the **colon** **at the end** of the first line.

Comment: Is this to be run from the Visual Studio Code terminal? Did not work for me

Comment: This solution is wrong for what the question is asking. akshitmahajan's answer is correct

Comment: @user1052610 I used pure mac os terminal

Answer (score 19):

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf ssh://
```

This one worked for me.

Comment: I suppose recent versions of `npm` need this.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to manually delete the offending package entry/reference in package-lock.json and then run the two commands in Alexey's answer.