# npm ignores git+https setting and uses git+ssh in package-lock.json

Tags: npm, package.json

We have multiple developers and an npm package that is installed form a public repository on github. while all developers usually have a github account, the CI server obviously doesn't (and usually doesn't need to).

The package from the public repository is installed using `git+https://github.com/<author>/<repo>#<branch>` however whenever a developer (with ssh installed) is installing another package the depencency in the `package-lock.json` is changed to `git+ssh...` which of course fails on the CI server.

is there any way to fix this behaviour?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this one? Faced with the exact same problem!

Comment: nope. went to develop inside docker containers

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the offending package-lock.json entry/reference and then running these two commands did the trick for me:

- *git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:*
- *git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://*

With credit to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61350264/1158234).

Comment: but this changes how git clones my regular repos

Answer (score 0):

I also came across the same issue and after some research, found a working solution.

You have to use the following format

```
git+https://git@github.com/<username>/<repo>.git
```

If you want to install a specific commit, then

```
git+https://git@github.com/<username>/<repo>.git#<commit_hash>
```

This will resolve correctly to `https` in the `package-lock.json` file as follows

```
"node_modules/<package-name>": {
    ...
    "resolved": "git+https://git@github.com/<username>/<repo>.git#<hash>",
    ...
}
```

if it still does not work,

1. delete the `package-lock.json`
2. clear npm cache `npm cache verify`
3. and `npm install`

Hope this answer would help someone... happy coding :)

Comment: Doesn't work for private repos. Will try to auth against the "git" user, which of course will not be valid. So you would have to put in your real github username here, `git+https://<username>@github.com/....`, which also is not practical, since it will require your token / auth in that case then