# How to solve npm install react-select failure with error : An unknown git error occurred, git@github.com :Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, npm

I am facing issues to install react-select for my react app, I tried below commands :

```bash
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org 
npm install --save react-select
```

I am getting below error:

```
An unknown git error occurred 
  git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
git@github.com :Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository 

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and
the repository exists
```

The currently installed versions in my system are node (v16.17.0), npm (8.19.2), react (18.2.0)

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: It appears your system is configured to use ssh authentication, so the error is explained here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey.    I would not suggest following this tutorial, instead this may be a viable workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61350264/3196753

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js is accessible, it is a public repository.

All you need to do is make sure `ssh -Tv github.com` is working, meaning it gives you a welcome message ("`Hi username! You've successfully authenticated...`")

Make sure your SSH key is [created](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) and [registered to your GitHub profile](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account), then try again your npm command.

Comment: I created the SSH key using instructions from https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent , however it still fails.

Comment: When other packages are getting installed with just npm install command, why does react-select always give trouble, what is the alternate way to get it?

Comment: @A.G.Progm.Enthusiast Does the `ssh -Tv git@github.com` work?

Comment: Well, ssh -Tv is giving a lots of debug1: <meesages> and ending with git@github.com : Permission denied (publickey). I would like to mention that mine one is 1source github which is a personalized account from my org. The actual github login credentials are different than my usual system login credentials. Thanks

Comment: @A.G.Progm.Enthusiast If you don't see a welcome message, you need to fix that fist. Follow [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh).